# DirectX 11 Switching from fullscreen -> windowed problem

Tags: c++, directx, directx-10, directx-11

I've been trawling various sites looking for the correct way to manage switching.

I thought I had cracked it but I've noticed a bizarre issue now that I am setting vertex and pixel shaders for a draw call.

I can swap to full screen using alt-enter and everything is fine, swapping back with either leave a blank window or render correctly but never continue to render any updates.

I.e it'll basically render one frame and any input is registered but not visible on screen till you swap to full screen.

Its clear I'm probably missing something with the swapchain  or devicecontext as I noticed using Flush() it would force it to work however I realize that clearly isn't the solution.

Render function snippet

```
    cube_.setToContext(context);
    context->VSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &cb_NeverChanges_ );
    context->VSSetConstantBuffers( 1, 1, &cb_ResizeChanges_ );
    context->VSSetConstantBuffers( 2, 1, &cb_FrameChanges_ );

    context->PSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &cb_NeverChanges_ );
    context->PSSetConstantBuffers( 1, 1, &cb_ResizeChanges_ );
    context->PSSetConstantBuffers( 2, 1, &cb_FrameChanges_ );

    context->VSSetShader( vertexShader_, nullptr, 0 );
    context->PSSetShader( pixelShader_, nullptr, 0 );
    context->Draw(cube_.getVertexTotal(), 0);

    dx_.getSwapChain()->Present(0,0);
```

Resize function which gets passed height/width from WM_SIZE case

```
if(FAILED(swapChain_->GetFullscreenState(&fullScreen, nullptr)))
        OutputDebugStringA("Failed to get fullscreen state.\n");

    swapChain_->GetDesc(&swapChainDesc);
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = !fullScreen;
    swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;
    if(fullScreen)
        swapChainDesc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;
    //Release renderTarget, depth stencil, depth stencil view, etc

    depthStencilView_->Release();
    depthStencil_->Release();
    renderTarget_->Release();

    if(FAILED(swapChain_->ResizeBuffers(swapChainDesc.BufferCount,width,height, swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format ,swapChainDesc.Flags)))
    {
        MessageBox( NULL, "Failed to resize buffers.", "Error", MB_OK );
        return false;
    }

    //recreate everything that was released
    if(!createRenderTarget())   
        return false;
    if(!createDepthStencils(width,height))
        return false;


    context_->OMSetRenderTargets( 1, &renderTarget_, depthStencilView_);
    D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;  //Should be a member of dx!
    vp.Width = (float)width;
    vp.Height = (float)height;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0;
    context_->RSSetViewports( 1, &vp );
```

Swap Chain setup with this

```
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
ZeroMemory( &swapChainDesc, sizeof( swapChainDesc ) );
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = height; 
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0; //auto =0, originally 60
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 0;
swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hWnd;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
swapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;
```

I've been testing this with D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG and no errors/warnings/leaks, any comments or input welcome.

Comment: Out of curiosity I added D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED flag as well as the debug flag and these seems to resolve the issue. 

I'm guessing I need to check to make sure another thread isn't active when swapping?

Comment: Ok, I think this is an nvidia bug only, friends tested with different ati cards and the issue never arose.

It was tested on two nvidia gtx 460's and the same issue happened. I suspect other nvidia cards behave the same.

If you have the one of the latest directx sdk's you can test this weird issue for yourself using the tutorial 7 example.

Hit alt-enter, hit alt-enter to swap back to windowed and the window becomes either blank/static - not updating.

The example will warn about not using resizeBuffers but my code is using it. (same effect)

Comment: Ok tested on nvidia 570 gtx and the problem also appears, so I think its highly likely to be nvidia only issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest nvidia drivers have resolved this issue (drivers 275.33) for the gtx460 and gtx570 tested on.

There obviously is a software explanation and answer to this problem but its working now and that is what I wanted.

Anyone reading this in the future and stumble upon the other fix please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

After porting from D3D10 to 11 my I ran into the same issues with my app. Everything blank when switching from fullscreen to windowed mode. Installing the latest GeForce drives resolved the issue (without any code changes).